# Mostrar imagem repeater ASP.NET através de base de dados SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

Consigo fazer com que todos os dados apareçam expecto a imagem alguém me pode ajudar?

Codigo

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="titulo">
            <h2>Gestor de Cursos</h2>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_curso" runat="server" >
                <HeaderTemplate>

                    <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <b>Cod.Curso</b>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <b>Curso</b>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <b>Descricao</b>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <b>Preco</b>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <b>Imagem</b>
                                </td>
                                
                            </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                
                
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("cod_produto")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("produto")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("descricao")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("preco")%>
                                </td>
                           
                                <td>  
                                    
                                     <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("dados") %>"'/>                  
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                </ItemTemplate>

                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>

                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Código por trás

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SYS4NOOBSConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();

            myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT produto.cod_produto, produto.descricao, produto.produto, produto.preco, ficheiro.dados FROM ficheiro INNER JOIN produto ON ficheiro.cod_ficheiro = produto.cod_ficheiro";

            myCommand.Connection = myConn;
            myConn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();


            List<curso> lista = new List<curso>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                curso obj = new curso();
                obj.cod_produto = reader.GetInt32(0);
                obj.produto = reader.GetString(1);
                obj.descricao = reader.GetString(2);
                obj.preco = reader.GetDecimal(3);
                obj.imagem = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])reader["dados"]);

                lista.Add(obj);
            }

          
            reader.Close();
            myConn.Close();


            myConn.Close();

            rpt_curso.DataSource = lista;
            rpt_curso.DataBind();

        }

        public class curso
        {
            public int cod_produto { get; set; }
            public string produto { get; set; }
            public string descricao { get; set; }
            public decimal preco { get; set; }
            public  string imagem { get; set; }
            public byte dados { get; set; }

        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: e como a imagem está salva no banco? qual o tipo do campo?  varbinary? precisar converter os dados de bytes para imagem, possivelmente salvar numca pasta para que possa ter um link e exibir

Comment: @RicardoPontual os campos da tabela da imagem relativamente a base de dados são varbinary.

Comment: Eu fiz a conversão mas agora a imagem aparece "partida"  vou editar o codigo e adicionar a imagem

Comment: Em vez de `<asp:Image>`, use `<asp:Literal>` para a imagem.

Answer (score -1):

Cara, baixei seu código e fiz uns testes. Um erro provável está na linha

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("dados") %>"'/>
```

nos testes não funcionou e notei que há um erro de sintaxe. Corrigindo, funcionou imediatamente. Abaixo vou deixar a linha editada por mim.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("dados") %>'/>
```

Somente fiz isso em todo seu código